# RESTful backend and socket.io to sync

Tags: node.js, rest, websocket, socket.io

Today, i had the idea of the following setup. Create a `nodejs` server along with `express` and `socket.io`. With express, i would create a RESTful API, which is connected to a mongo. BackboneJS or similar would connect the client to that REST API.
Now every time the mongodb(ie the data in it iam interested in) changes, socket.io would fire an event to the client, which would carry a courser to the data which has changed. The client then would trigger the appropriate AJAX requests to the REST to get the new data, where it needs it.

So, the socket.io connection would behave like a synchronize trigger. It would be there for the entire visit and could also manage sessions that way. All the payload would be send over http.

Pros:

- REST API for use with other clients than web
- Auth could be done entirely over socket.io. Only sending token along with REST requests.
- Use the benefits of REST.
- Would also play nicely with pub/sub service like Redis'

Cons:

- Greater overhead, than using pure socket.io.

What do you think, are there any great disadvantages i did not think of?

Comment: You essentially want to reinvent CouchDB as it seems.

Comment: Really? But CouchDB doesn't push the change stream, does it?

Comment: In case you mean if it can push changes to another instance then yes, yes it can using continuous replication.

Comment: Even better: why not push the changes directly using socket.io instead of doing a trigger-pull combi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with @CharlieKey, you should send the updated data rather than re-requesting.

This is exactly what Tower is doing:

- save some data: https://github.com/viatropos/tower/blob/development/src/tower/model/persistence.coffee#L77
- insert into mongodb (cursor is a query/persistence abstraction): https://github.com/viatropos/tower/blob/development/src/tower/model/cursor/persistence.coffee#L29
- notify sockets: https://github.com/viatropos/tower/blob/development/src/tower/model/cursor/persistence.coffee#L68
- emit updated records to client: https://github.com/viatropos/tower/blob/development/src/tower/server/net/connection.coffee#L62

The disadvantage of using sockets as a trigger to re-request with Ajax is that every connected client will have to fetch the data, so if 100 people are on your site there's going to be 100 HTTP requests every time data changes - where you could just reuse the socket connections.

Comment: Thanks for this! So would you still load the initial state by http and only the changes by sockets? You're right with your example, these 100 http request would even come in at the very same time.. I thought of the advantage, that i could design a webapp completely without pushing and use pushing only sporadically in some places. So i could leverage the convenient express routing and set a push layer on top of that.

Comment: Yes, I would still load the initial state with HTTP, then the changes with sockets. But for the initial state, I would bootstrap the JSON into the HTML in a script tag so you don't have to make an Ajax call after the page loads (e.g. `<script>App.bootstrap({posts: [...]})</script>`). You still want the REST API though, so you can fully run your app without sockets, and sockets are basically an enhancement.

Comment: Yup, none of the links seem to work. Please update the links

Answer (score 3):

I think that pushing the updated data with the socket.io event would be better than re-requesting the lastest. Even better you could only push the modified pieces of data decreasing the amount of data sent over the line. Overall though a interesting idea.

Comment: Thank you! btw: modulus.io looks promising!

Comment: upvoted how do you keep this in sync though, for example when the new data arrives the client was disconnected for some reason and then connects later, they miss the new data

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into [Now.js](https://github.com/Flotype/now) since it does pretty much exactly what you need.

It creates a namespace which is shared among the client and server. The server can call functions on the client directly and vice versa.

That is if you insist on your current infrastructure decision to use MongoDB and Node.js, otherwise there would be [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) which is a full web server and document database with sophisticated replication mechanisms built-in.

Comment: Thank you, yeah i know Now.js. What do you think of particularly? Calling the client requests from within the server directly?

Comment: Well, that is a possibility, yes. You could inform every client that is listening that there is fresh data to be fetched for example. You could even push the data directly without having the client request it too.